# Why is Inspecting the DOM element showing something diff than using jQuery ID selector in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on displaying a graphic on a website. For some reason, when I inspect the element I see this:

```
<div id="canvas-daily" style="position:relative;" ng-if="currentMode == 'day'"      class="ng-scope"><div class="circle-background"></div></div>
```

But when I do document.getElementById("canvas-daily") in my console I get a svg graphic inside the parent (canvas-daily) ID div. Why would this be happening and how can I fix/hack into this to append the content that is obviously there?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - this answer has been rendered obsolete by edits the OP made to their question.  It has not been deleted yet because of the conversation happening in comments.

---

To find the DOM element shown in the HTML in your question, you would just use this:

```
document.getElementById("canvas-daily")
```

Do NOT include the `#` in the string you pass to `document.getElementById()`.  That is only used with more generic functions that accept CSS selectors like `document.querySelectorAll()`.  `document.getElementById()` just takes a plain string that matches the ID you are looking for.

Comment: that was a typo sorry. I still see different content. I just thought inspecting the dom and doing jquery or native JS would show me the same thing?

Comment: @StackJuice2 - first off, you should NEVER have duplicate IDs anywhere in your document.  If you have that, then `document.getElementById()` is not necessarily going to give you the one you want.  Secondly, perhaps it has to do with the timing of when you call `document.getElementById("canvas-daily")`.  You are not inspecting the DOM at the exactly same moment that `document.getElementById("canvas-daily")` is running.

Comment: Ok but should they not show the same content? That doesn't make sense to me. If I inspect the dom, I'm basically inspect the ID in the same fashion minutes after the content has loaded. Why would they be diff?

Comment: @StackJuice2 - code can change the DOM.  I have no idea what's going on in your page with code to have any idea.  We might be able to help if you showed a lot more context here.  As your question stands now, there's simply not enough relevant information for us to have any idea what's going on (and thus probably why you're getting downvotes).  Plus, we don't even really know what ultimate thing you're trying to do to that page so can't even help there either.  If you can describe what you're actually trying to accomplish and post a link to the page in question, we might be able to help.

Comment: It would be such a long question that I thought I wouldn't get any replies. Do you mind if I email you my question somehow when I try to articulate it clearer and simpler?

Comment: email is generally not appropriate for this forum and I make it a policy to keep my help public here in the forum and not to pass around my email.  Your job is to include enough relevant information in your question that we can help you without including the entire kitchen sink.  If you have a public version of the page, you can post a link to that along with some of the more relevant portions of the code.